# how to find users in AD that are active, have a certificate and have specific attributes present and

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

If I use Powershell and enter:

`Get-Aduser -Identity user1 -Properties*`

then I get a list of the properties that I can search in AD.

I am trying to find all users in AD that have certificates (basically to filter out users that have the Certificates field empty), are active (for the past 90 days), user account is not disabled and extensionattribute11 is "R". I want to be able to count all these categories of users separately, for example, how many users have Certificates field with a value in it (regardless the value) and how many have empty, how many users have extensionattribute11 is "R", and so on

Comment: You are looking to take advantage of `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter`. Is there something you have tried? Looking for non empty fields I'm sure is already covered here. Looking for active accounts has a caveat since you would just be getting results from one DC. You might have to look up that one separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, because at the beginning you say you want to filter OUT any user who has a blank Certificates attribute.  Then, at the end, you say you want to count "how many have empty".  If that's the case, you don't want to filter them out.  You also say you want to filter for users who have "R" but you don't state if you want users who don't have "R" so I assume you want all enabled users active in the last 90 days with those properties.  So you only want to filter OUT disabled users and users inactive for 90 days.   That just sounds like you need to sort your selected properties.  This would filter OUT any users who are disabled or inactive for more than 90 days, but show you anyone else and display their properties, sorted first on Certificates, then extensionAttribute11.

```
$Properties = "Certificates, DisplayName, LastLogonTimeStamp, Enabled, extensionAttribute11"
Get-ADUser -Filter {(LastLogonTimeStamp -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) -and enabled -eq $true)} -Properties $Properties | select $Properties | sort Certificates, extensionAttribute11 | Export-Csv file.csv
```

Is that your goal?